# GNU-Make: how to copy files from source to destination

Tags: gnu-make

I know this is a basic question but I'm missing something fundamental about makefiles.

Take this simple rule/action:

```
doc:  ${SRC_DIR}/doc/dir1/file1.pdf  ${SRC_DIR}/doc/dir1/file2.pdf
    cp $? ${DEST_DIR}/doc/
```

the first time I run it, it copies file1.pdf and file2.pdf to the destination/doc directory. Perfect.    I'm expecting the next time I run it, for it to do nothing.  The source files haven't changed, aren't they a dependency?  But when I run I get :

cp : cannot create regular file ..... :Permission denied.

so, 2 questions:
1) Why is it trying to do it again?  When I run make -d I see it eventually says:    No need to remake target .../file1.pdf   and .../file2.pdf  but then
it says : must remake target 'doc'
If it doesn't need to make either pdf file, why does it need to make doc?

2) say the pdf files had changed in the source, they are read only though, so it gets the permission denied error.  How do you get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A make rule:

```
target: preqreq0 prereq1...
    command
    ...
```

says that `target` needs to be (re)made if it does not exist or is older than
any of the prerequisites `preqreq0 prereq1...`, and that `target` shall be
(re)made by running the recipe `command ...`.

Your rule:

```
doc:  ${SRC_DIR}/doc/dir1/file1.pdf  ${SRC_DIR}/doc/dir1/file2.pdf
    cp $? ${DEST_DIR}/doc/
```

never creates a file or directory `doc`, so `doc` will never exist when
the rule is evaluated (unless you create `doc` by other means), so the recipe
will always be run.

The kind of target that I believe you want `doc` to be is a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html),
but you are going about it wrongly. A reasonable makefile for the purpose would
be:

```
SRC_DIR := .
DEST_DIR := .
PDFS := file1.pdf file2.pdf
PDF_TARGS := $(patsubst %,$(DEST_DIR)/doc/%,$(PDFS))

.PHONY: doc clean

doc: $(PDF_TARGS)

$(DEST_DIR)/doc/%.pdf: $(SRC_DIR)/doc/dir1/%.pdf 
    cp $< $@


clean:
    rm -f $(PDF_TARGS)
```

I recommend [The GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

As for your second problem, how to overwrite "readonly" files, it is unrelated to `make`.
You cannot overwrite files to which you do not have write permission, regardless
of the means by which you try to do it. You must get write permission to any files
that you need to write to. It is a system administration matter. If you do not
understand file permissions you may find help at sister-site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
or [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: It's possible you don't have permissions to write, but you do have permissions to change permissions... in which case you can give the file write permissions with the command `chmod u+w <filename>` in your recipe before you copy.  If that doesn't work then as Mike says, it's a system admin issue.

Comment: @M.E.A Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)